# hlsl debugging in vs13 graphics diagnostics

Tags: visual-studio-2013, hlsl

I am trying to debug a shader in visual studio 2013 (via graphics diagnostics engine) but I am having the following message...

**This graphics diagnostics engine failed to build shader trace and therefore it is unable to debug shader.**

When I configured the setting the configuration setting was set to "Debug". And the command line I used is as follows :

**fxc /Zi /Od /Fo"Skin.fxo" /fx"_5_0" /nologo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared an array which was used by the shader code.. However the array was overflowing and since it was built outside visual so it didnot give any error message.